# How to combine two dataframe based on column route?

Tags: python, pandas

Column route represents the point for each location

So I have two tables like this, my question is how to calculate the sum of the load difference between the two tables if the route has to match with every location [1,2,3,4,5]

for example:

df1['Route'] = [1,5] and df2['Route'] = [2,3,4] then the result is [[1,5],[2,3,4]] with sum
of load difference = 368.93 + (-10325.19) = -9956,26

df1

| index | Route | Total Distance | Total Demand | Total Time | Total Volume | Load Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1,5 | 2257 | 642.46 | 173 | 4631.07 | 368.93 |
| 18 | 1,3,4 | 2179 | 633.65 | 167 | 4409.15 | 590.85 |
| 7 | 1,4 | 2152 | 538.2 | 165 | 3700.13 | 1299.87 |
| 24 | 3,4,5 | 2086 | 508.09 | 160 | 3387.27 | 1612.73 |
| 6 | 1,3 | 2146 | 479.46 | 165 | 3296.29 | 1703.71 |
| 0 | 1 | 2104 | 384.01 | 161 | 2576.07 | 2423.93 |
| 14 | 4,5 | 1775 | 412.64 | 136 | 2338.29 | 2661.71 |
| 13 | 3,5 | 2029 | 353.9 | 156 | 2300.35 | 2699.65 |
| 12 | 3,4 | 1881 | 249.64 | 144 | 1497.84 | 3502.16 |
| 4 | 5 | 1570 | 258.45 | 120 | 1292.25 | 3707.75 |
| 3 | 4 | 1570 | 154.19 | 120 | 770.95 | 4229.05 |
| 2 | 3 | 1848 | 95.45 | 142 | 564.75 | 4435.25 |
| 19 | 1,3,5 | 2327 | 737.91 | 179 | 5503.58 | -503.58 |
| 20 | 1,4,5 | 2357 | 796.65 | 181 | 6008.07 | -1008.07 |
| 28 | 1,3,4,5 | 2384 | 892.1 | 183 | 6802.26 | -1802.26 |
| 1 | 2 | 1960 | 2510.39 | 150 | 15689.94 | -10689.94 |
| 9 | 2,3 | 1986 | 2605.84 | 152 | 16503.65 | -11503.65 |
| 10 | 2,4 | 1994 | 2664.58 | 153 | 16986.7 | -11986.7 |
| 21 | 2,3,4 | 2019 | 2760.03 | 155 | 17825.19 | -12825.19 |
| 11 | 2,5 | 2097 | 2768.84 | 161 | 18574.3 | -13574.3 |
| 5 | 1,2 | 2140 | 2894.4 | 164 | 19778.4 | -14778.4 |
| 22 | 2,3,5 | 2167 | 2864.29 | 166 | 19811.34 | -14811.34 |
| 23 | 2,4,5 | 2199 | 2923.03 | 169 | 20583.0 | -15583.0 |
| 15 | 1,2,3 | 2166 | 2989.85 | 166 | 20679.8 | -15679.8 |
| 16 | 1,2,4 | 2174 | 3048.59 | 167 | 21213.11 | -16213.11 |
| 29 | 2,3,4,5 | 2224 | 3018.48 | 171 | 21506.67 | -16506.67 |
| 25 | 1,2,3,4 | 2199 | 3144.04 | 169 | 22139.28 | -17139.28 |
| 17 | 1,2,5 | 2277 | 3152.85 | 175 | 22989.53 | -17989.53 |
| 26 | 1,2,3,5 | 2347 | 3248.3 | 180 | 24362.25 | -19362.25 |
| 27 | 1,2,4,5 | 2379 | 3307.04 | 183 | 25216.18 | -20216.18 |
| 30 | 1,2,3,4,5 | 2404 | 3402.49 | 184 | 26085.76 | -21085.76 |

df2

| index | Route | Total Distance | Total Demand | Total Time | Total Volume | Load Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 1,3,4,5 | 2384 | 892.1 | 183 | 6802.26 | 697.74 |
| 20 | 1,4,5 | 2357 | 796.65 | 181 | 6008.07 | 1491.93 |
| 19 | 1,3,5 | 2327 | 737.91 | 179 | 5503.58 | 1996.42 |
| 8 | 1,5 | 2257 | 642.46 | 173 | 4631.07 | 2868.93 |
| 18 | 1,3,4 | 2179 | 633.65 | 167 | 4409.15 | 3090.85 |
| 7 | 1,4 | 2152 | 538.2 | 165 | 3700.13 | 3799.87 |
| 24 | 3,4,5 | 2086 | 508.09 | 160 | 3387.27 | 4112.73 |
| 6 | 1,3 | 2146 | 479.46 | 165 | 3296.29 | 4203.71 |
| 0 | 1 | 2104 | 384.01 | 161 | 2576.07 | 4923.93 |
| 14 | 4,5 | 1775 | 412.64 | 136 | 2338.29 | 5161.71 |
| 13 | 3,5 | 2029 | 353.9 | 156 | 2300.35 | 5199.65 |
| 12 | 3,4 | 1881 | 249.64 | 144 | 1497.84 | 6002.16 |
| 4 | 5 | 1570 | 258.45 | 120 | 1292.25 | 6207.75 |
| 3 | 4 | 1570 | 154.19 | 120 | 770.95 | 6729.05 |
| 2 | 3 | 1848 | 95.45 | 142 | 564.75 | 6935.25 |
| 1 | 2 | 1960 | 2510.39 | 150 | 15689.94 | -8189.94 |
| 9 | 2,3 | 1986 | 2605.84 | 152 | 16503.65 | -9003.65 |
| 10 | 2,4 | 1994 | 2664.58 | 153 | 16986.7 | -9486.7 |
| 21 | 2,3,4 | 2019 | 2760.03 | 155 | 17825.19 | -10325.19 |
| 11 | 2,5 | 2097 | 2768.84 | 161 | 18574.3 | -11074.3 |
| 5 | 1,2 | 2140 | 2894.4 | 164 | 19778.4 | -12278.4 |
| 22 | 2,3,5 | 2167 | 2864.29 | 166 | 19811.34 | -12311.34 |
| 23 | 2,4,5 | 2199 | 2923.03 | 169 | 20583.0 | -13083.0 |
| 15 | 1,2,3 | 2166 | 2989.85 | 166 | 20679.8 | -13179.8 |
| 16 | 1,2,4 | 2174 | 3048.59 | 167 | 21213.11 | -13713.11 |
| 29 | 2,3,4,5 | 2224 | 3018.48 | 171 | 21506.67 | -14006.67 |
| 25 | 1,2,3,4 | 2199 | 3144.04 | 169 | 22139.28 | -14639.28 |
| 17 | 1,2,5 | 2277 | 3152.85 | 175 | 22989.53 | -15489.53 |
| 26 | 1,2,3,5 | 2347 | 3248.3 | 180 | 24362.25 | -16862.25 |
| 27 | 1,2,4,5 | 2379 | 3307.04 | 183 | 25216.18 | -17716.18 |
| 30 | 1,2,3,4,5 | 2404 | 3402.49 | 184 | 26085.76 | -18585.76 |

Comment: May I presume the route for each dataframe is unduplicated?

Comment: it was duplicated for column Route, Total Distance, Total Demand, Total Time, and Total Volume, but not for column Load Difference, so basically Load difference column is CONSTRAIN - total volume,

Comment: CONSTRAIN for df1 is 5000 and df2 is 7500, and both dataframe is sorted by the load difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

```py
import numpy as np

prime_map = {k:v for k,v in zip("12345", [2,3,5,7,11])}

def road_key_to_number(x):
    return np.prod(list(prime_map[k] for k in x.split(",")))


df1["key"] = df1["Route"].apply(road_key_to_number)
df2["key"] = df2["Route"].apply(road_key_to_number)
df2["pair_key"] = np.prod(list(prime_map.values())) / df2["key"]
data = df1.merge(df2, left_on = "key", right_on="pair_key")
data["diff"] = (data["Load Difference_x"] + data["Load Difference_y"])
```

### Output

```
    Route_x  Route_y      diff
0       1,5    2,3,4  -9956.26
1     1,3,4      2,5 -10483.45
2       1,4    2,3,5 -11011.47
3     3,4,5      1,2 -10665.67
4       1,3    2,4,5 -11379.29
5         1  2,3,4,5 -11582.74
6       4,5    1,2,3 -10518.09
7       3,5    1,2,4 -11013.46
8       3,4    1,2,5 -11987.37
9         5  1,2,3,4 -10931.53
10        4  1,2,3,5 -12633.20
11        3  1,2,4,5 -13280.93
12    1,3,5      2,4  -9990.28
13    1,4,5      2,3 -10011.72
14  1,3,4,5        2  -9992.20
15        2  1,3,4,5  -9992.20
16      2,3    1,4,5 -10011.72
17      2,4    1,3,5  -9990.28
18    2,3,4      1,5  -9956.26
19      2,5    1,3,4 -10483.45
20      1,2    3,4,5 -10665.67
21    2,3,5      1,4 -11011.47
22    2,4,5      1,3 -11379.29
23    1,2,3      4,5 -10518.09
24    1,2,4      3,5 -11013.46
25  2,3,4,5        1 -11582.74
26  1,2,3,4        5 -10931.53
27    1,2,5      3,4 -11987.37
28  1,2,3,5        4 -12633.20
29  1,2,4,5        3 -13280.93
```

### Explanation

- The key idea is to match two `df.Route` to calculate the diff between them.
- Here `prime_map` is using a method called `Arithmeticization`, it has been used in `Metamathematics` to prove `Gödel's incompleteness theorems`

  - Each node in the route has a unique prime number, so, we can use a unique product from them to represent a road, and it is **order-independent**, which means `1,2,4` equal `4,2,1`
  - You also could use another method like `intersection` or `union` to represent it.

### Reference

- [Metamathematics - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamathematics)
- [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems)

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, never heard of Gödel's incompleteness theorems, but will read them for sure